# Property assignment not working in Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, this

I have a very simple injectable service in TypeScript for Angular 4. It fetches a JSON file as an array from the network. Afterwards, it should store the returned array in one of its properties, called `data`. `data` can then be accessed by other classes with the method `getData()`.

My problem is that the assignment operation is ignored. Doing `this.data = data` does not actually change `this.data`. Everything else is working perfectly fine.

The code of the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class JsonFetcherService {
  private data: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.data = null;
  }

  public fetch(url: string): void {
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(this.setData);
  }

  private setData(data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public getData(): any {
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

The code of a very simple class that uses the service:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { JsonFetcherService } from '../jsonFetcherService/JsonFetcherService';

@Component({
    selector: 'json-fetcher-example',
    templateUrl: './JsonFetcherExample.html'
})
export class JsonFetcherExample {
    constructor(private json: JsonFetcherService) {
        this.json.fetch('http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json');
    }
}
```

#### Update:

In addition to the issue of the binding of `this`, the method used here, *subscribe*, is asynchronous. The code to be executed after the JSON file is fetched needs to be moved inside the callback.

```
public fetch(url: string, myFunction) {
  const test = this.http.get(url);
  test.subscribe((data)=> {
    this.data = data;
    myFunction();
  });
}
```

Comment: `.subscribe(this.setData);` should be `.subscribe((data)=>this.setData(data));` or `.subscribe(this.setData.bind(this));`. You will lose the global `this` inside the callback if you omit the paranthesis `()` while writing the callback.

Comment: @echonax The main cause of the problem is actually a combination of the context of `this` and of an asynchronous call, the duplicate you marked only partially answers the problem.

Comment: So the second part becomes the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call :-)

Answer (score 2):

This issue here is the context of 'this' for "this.data". Inside the this.setData() function 'this' is actually referring to the observable. try this to fix it:

```
let setData = (data)=> {
  this.data = data;
}
```

Using Arrow notation allows the 'this' context to remain in the class rather than the observable.

More info on 
[Arrow Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what you meant. I was using the arrow notation when I first got the problem. I did: `this.http.get(url).subscribe((data)=> { this.data = data; });`. I'm not sure where I should put the `let`.

Comment: `this.http.get(url).subscribe((data)=> { this.data = data; });` should work, `this.http.get(url).subscribe(this.setData);` should not.

Comment: @Louis-MarieMatthews Either do what Harry suggested or change the setData function definition to a variable as in my answer. Every function has a 'this' unless you use arrow notation.

Comment: Maybe you are expecting something like this `this.http.get(url).subscribe((data) => this.setData(data));` using the arrow notation

Comment: Acutally, the problem was twofold: I wasn't using array notation and the method is asynchronous. This meant `console.log` was called before `this.data = data`. I was originally using arrow notation, but because I didn't know the method was asynchronous, I tried to use a standard method instead, and this is the method I posted in my code snippet above.